# Compare 2 lists , t-test problem?

Tags: statistics

I have 2 lists, the first list those that bought books and the second the list readers of the same books. I want to compare them to see if there is scientific difference between them. I am planning to use t-test "two sample assuming unequal variance". Is there any other test than t-test I should consider while comparing the 2 lists ?

An example of the 2 lists

```
Book Name - Bought - Read 
B1 - 33 - 35 
B2 - 22 - 29
B3 - 5 - 3
B4 - 8 - 17
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [permutation test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resampling_%28statistics%29#Permutation_tests).

Comment: Perhaps some additional detail would help the OP.

Comment: I add an example